# App Engine deploy cannot find ssh command

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, npm

I am trying to use a private git repository as a package source for npm in my node.js app. That is, I have the following line in my package.json dependencies:

```
"mypackage": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/myusername/mypackage.git#dev",
```

This works fine on my machine, but I cannot deploy to the App Engine. When I run `gcloud app deploy` there is an error building the Docker container. When it runs the npm install command an error occurs because git cannot clone my repository due to a missing ssh command.

```
Step #1: npm ERR! Error while executing:
Step #1: npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@bitbucket.org/tappshq/tp-nodejs-api-commons.git
Step #1: npm ERR! 
Step #1: npm ERR! error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
Step #1: npm ERR! fatal: unable to fork
Step #1: npm ERR! 
Step #1: npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
Step #1: 
Step #1: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
Step #1: npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2018-01-17T16_05_18_034Z-debug.log
Step #1: The command '/bin/sh -c npm install --unsafe-perm ||   ((if [ -f npm-debug.log ]; then       cat npm-debug.log;     fi) && false)' returned a non-zero code: 1
Finished Step #1
```

Is there another way to do this? Is ssh supposed to be missing at this point? Because if I try to debug an instance, it shows an existing ssh command? I also tried using https, but bitbucket does not allow me to login via https without using 2-factor authentication which won't work here.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?